# Clarity Design System CSS don't work

Tags: angular, ionic2, vmware-clarity

I did everything on this post [Clarity Design System-Get Started](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/get-started) but I can't make it work.
I installed Clarity UI on a new ionic proyect, but when I tried to add a simple Card example or anything else:

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
            <div class="card-title">
                Block
            </div>
            <div class="card-text">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Footer Action 1</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link">Footer Action 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS has not worked. 
This is how it looks [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzB3s.png)

What I missed? CSS and JS files fails to be referenced by anything like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/node_modules/clarity-ui/clarity-ui.min.css">
```

I'm new working with **Ionic2 + Angular**, and I'm new with Clarity

Comment: Welcome! Please read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to help us help you. We need to understand what specifically you have done and what the error is.

Comment: You're right Philip, sorry. I add some addicional information. I just follow this tutorial, anything else I found say just same information.

Comment: I have not used clarity, but the process is probably similar to using font-awesome.  Take a look at [this](https://charlouze.github.io/ionic/2017/05/31/Ionic-3-and-Font-Awesome.html) and see if it can be augmented for the css portion of this clarity thing.

Comment: Thanks again Philip!!I finally found this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Philip!! I read this article and I finally found this file **{{ROOT}}\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\config\copy.config.js** where I add this:

```
copyClarityIcons: {
    src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.css'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/css'
},
copyClarityElements: {
    src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js','{{ROOT}}/node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.js'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/js'
},
copyClarityCSS: {
    src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/clarity-ui/clarity-ui.min.css'],
    dest: '{{WWW}}/assets/css'
}
```

It works!!